# Java: How can I load an external class into a gui

Tags: java, swing

I'm looking for a specific functionality. I want to load a class that extends `JPanel` for instance and show that `JPanel` on a separate GUI class.

I'm looking for the ability to switch several of these classes out at will. I have an idea for an educational game software and the classes would be the different games.

I do realize that I can instantiate an instance of each class in my GUI class, but I ran into the issue of them not displaying properly when I try to switch between them. `repaint()` only works on the last class I added to my content pane. Not sure why as the multiple classes I instantiate are present, it just seems to ignore the preceding classes.

How to swap components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use CardLayout to switch all the component or add/remove them calling

```
container.revalidate(); 
container.repaint();
```

Comment: +2 for CardLayout, -1 for that silly method of adding and removing components (unnecessary except in rare situations - should not be encouraged).

Comment: BTW - I should clarify.  'Necessary' is when the programmer goes to add a new set of components to a `CardLayout`, and the app. falls over with an [OutOfMemoryError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).  (OK - I'm being difficult - it's just that I have come to expect better from you).

Comment: Of course CardLayout is better but there is an alternative way. JUst need to remember the new component size should be the same as the old to avoid distortions.

Comment: CardLayout is working great for what i wanted...thanks everyone for your input :D